# Use DFS to replicate file shares to two new servers?

Tags: windows-server-2016, dfs, dfs-r

Trying to find the best way to migrate file shares on one server we are deprecating to a new server. We will then use dfs from this new server to replicate with another new machine for our final setup.

I thought I’d just use dfs to replicate from the old machine to the new one, but then read about some potential issues (however this was on older server OS they had issues). I’ve seen numerous 3rd party tools and robocopy as recommendations for the initial migration.

So my question is am I overthinking this and can I just use DFS on the old server to replicate to one of the new servers then I can setup my final DFS group between the two new servers?

TYIA!

Comment: I did this way because I had to keep the old server alive due to the fact that I had migrate live from one to a norther server while the application was used on both servers. so it's possible but remember that it takes a bit time ;)

Comment: Thanks! Did you just remove the old server from DFS when done?

Comment: yes, after I used win merge to verify all files on existence this was the way I did remind to set the new server as primary and one way replica if possible moreover its the lazy way to do so